# Sql Server agent Job the first business day of each month

Tags: sql-server, jobs, agent

How can I schedule to run once on the first business day of every month in SQL Server JOB application?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Frequency, you can choose "The first weekday of every 1 month(s)".
[image: SQL Agent New Job Schedule]

It won't handle holidays, but as far as I know that's the closest you can get with the schedule configuration.